# rename folders by removing substring

Tags: rename

I have a list of folders `video_0001` `video_0002` `video_0003` ...
How do I rename them all to `0001` `0002` `0003` ... ? I tried

`mv video_{0001..0003} {0001..0003}` but it does not work

Comment: lazy gui way using krusader and multi-rename which is krename, add a counter for filename with 4 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a `for` loop by starting at the 7th character of each file (remember counting starts at 0) and saving the last 4 characters of each file.

```
for f in video_*; do mv $f ${f:6:4}; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Install `rename` by

```
sudo apt install rename
```

and run

```
rename s/video_// *
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness:

- with `mmv` (from package `mmv`):

  ```
  mmv -n 'video_*' '#1'
  ```
- with `zsh` and `zmv`

  ```
   zsh
   autoload zmv

   zmv -n 'video_(*)' '$1'
  ```

In both the above, remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

A more portable shell loop:

```
    for f in video_*; do echo mv "$f" "${f#*_}"; done
```

remove the `echo` similarly. Note that `#*_` removes the shortest prefix; in circumstances where you wish to remove the longest prefix like `my_long_video_1234` change to `##*_`.